# mongoose driver not inserting data while in a loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to load a bunch of data from a file into my mongoDB;
Using node: v8.9.1, mongoose: ^4.10.8, MongoDB v3.4.1 - running on Win 10.

only a couple elements from the document are being inserted. I suspect something in the schema, but I cant be sure, the console.log reflects the date 100% correctly.

This is my data:    **/_mock_data/test.json**

```
[{
    "AUTHOR":"Anthony Johnson",
    "TITLE":"A Little March",
    "COLLECTION_TITLE":"Classic Fairytails for Children",
    "FORMAT":"Trade Paperback",
    "PUBLISHER":"Randon House",
    "SKU":"10055",
    "SUGGESTED_GRADE_LEVEL":[6],
    "STATE_RATING":[{"NY":[1]}, {"PA":[1]}, {"VA":[3]}],
    "AUDIO_LINK":""
},...]
```

Here's the code: **app.js** (reduced to what's relevant)

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
    mongoose.Promise = require( 'bluebird' );

app.use( bodyParser.json() );

var Catalog = require( './models/catalog' );

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {server: { poolSize: 5 }});
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get( '/api/loadCatalog', function( req, res ) {
    var catalog = require( './_mock_data/test.json' );

    for ( var i in catalog ) {

        Catalog.create( catalog[i] );
        console.log( catalog[i] );

    };

});

app.listen( 3000, function() {
    console.log( 'server started on port 3000' );
});
```

**/models/catalog**

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );

// catalog schema
var catalogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    author : {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }
    ,title : {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }
    ,collection_title : {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }
    ,format : {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }
    ,publisher : {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }
    ,sku : {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }
    ,suggested_grade_level : {
        type: Array
        ,required: false
    }
    ,state_rating : {
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
        ,required: false
    }
    ,audio_link : {
        type: String
        ,required: false
    }
});

var Catalog = module.exports = mongoose.model( 'Catalog', catalogSchema );

// Get Items
module.exports.getItems = function( callback, limit ) {
    Catalog.find( callback ).limit( limit );
};

// Add Item
module.exports.addItem = function( item, callback ) {
    Catalog.create( item, callback );
};
```

and the errors I'm getting -

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in Anthony Johnson
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in A Little March
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in Classic Fairytails for Children
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in Trade Paperback
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in Randon House
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in 10055
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in 6
```

So the data I get looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a28fa8503511d1d14054c92"),
    "state_rating" : [ ],
    "suggested_grade_level" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

All the string data errored and the object data went in, The "actual" data is an array of 1000's, and this is a one time import, yes I could use mongo cli to do the import, but I am only developing locally, Eventually I'll be shoving this data to an Atlas account, and as far as I can tell, this will be the way to get the data in place.

the console.log inside the loop gives me the actual data

```
Anthony Johnson
A Little March
Classic Fairytails for Children
Trade Paperback
Randon House
10055
[ 6 ]
[ { NY: [ 1 ] }, { PA: [ 1 ] }, { VA: [ 3 ] } ]
```

I'm pretty sure Im missing something basic about using the model to use the schema in this way... my "get" and "add" work fine...maybe I should do the loop in the model, not the app...

Comment: You are passing `catalog[i]`. I think it should include the key with it. like `Catalog.create( {your_key:catalog[i]});`

Comment: yes Kiran,
Thank you - I see that it is unclear the way i posted it - there should be an array around the object, as the file is an array. I have fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a small change that loop,

```
   for ( var i in catalog ) {
    var key = convertStringToCamelCase(i);
    Catalog.create( {key : catalog[i]} );
    console.log( {key : catalog[i]} );

    };
```

To convert the key to lower and camel case to match with the schema, you can create a small helper function like this

```
function convertStringToCamelCase(str_original){
    var str = str_original.toLowerCase();
    return str.split(' ').map(function(item, index){
        return index !== 0 
            ? item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.substr(1) 
            : item.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + item.substr(1);
    }).join('');
```

}

Comment: Kiran, Thank you - I was half curious if there was a case sensitivity thing going on, I have been spoiled (or ruined) by working in a case-less language for close to 20 years, and it still catches me. I changed the case on the keys in the file to match the case in the schema - works fine.